# What data gets sent to the server when I submit from a form?

Tags: html, css

I would like to issue a submit from my form and have data sent back to the server. Is the only data sent to the server that which appears within the form ( xxx fields etc.) or will the data such as that in the input fields yyy also be sent to the server?

```
<form action="/adminTopic/Edit" method="post">   

xxx

</form>

yyy
```

Comment: Is having input fields outside of forms even valid HTML? If not, the answer might vary from browser to browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the fields within the form will be submitted, in this case only xxx sent back to the server

Comment: Welcome, you might take note at @Ulrich Schwarz comment as well, make sure it is valid HTML